Post json stub file to Wiremock server
I can use http post to post mapping definition to Wiremock
http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings

I tried to post stub body json file to
http://localhost:8080/__admin/__files

Does not work. Is there any way to post stub files via Wiremock http server, to "__files" folder ?

It looks like you are using the wrong path to access the files admin API.  You should be using the following method and path:
PUT /__admin/files/{fileId}
The {fileId} is the name of the file.
More information on the admin API can be found here:
https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/admin-api-reference/#tag/Files

HTTP put file returns 200 OK . I can see names of the uploaded files. But when I try to read contents "Get file by ID": 404. That is "/__admin/files/file_name.json". ?

Seems to work OK anyway. I can now send stub body json files to Wiremock, as I was looking for. Wiremock only don't want to "show" contents of upoaded files.
